# Solution for sudo chmod 700 /bin && sudo chmod 700 /bin

Tags: permissions, chmod

I accidentally run

```
sudo chmod 700 /bin && sudo chmod 700 /bin
```

Then I couldn't run sudo or any commands again please is there a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accidentally deleted /usr/ directory in CentOS 8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571531/accidentally-deleted-usr-directory-in-centos-8)

Comment: Some one has tried to edit your question to make it `/bin/*`. This is not what you said. However it may be what you intended, as the two commands are currently identical. Can you tell us what you intended.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571531/accidentally-deleted-usr-directory-in-centos-8 (this one looks fixable).

Answer (score 5):

Running

```
sudo chmod 700 /bin && sudo chmod 700 /bin
```

would only change the permissions on the `/bin` directory itself, or if it’s a symlink, the directory it points to. This would make the contents of the directory inaccessible to non-root users, but the damage is limited.

You can recover by logging in as root, or booting into a rescue environment (both of these require knowing the root password), or booting from a rescue device, and then running

```
chmod 755 /bin
```

You don’t need to re-install.